# Ubuntu 16.04 refuses to log in after the laptop battery runs out while running sfill

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, login, encryption

Right, so, I wanted to test various security tools for Ubuntu, and one was sfill, which I left running while I went to do some business. Unfortunately, I forgot to plug the laptop in, and so the power ran out while I was away. However, after I plugged it back in and restarted the computer, I was no longer able to log in. The login screen starts up just fine, but when I enter my password, the screen just goes blank for a few seconds, and then goes back to the login screen.

Now, since I'm able to open Guest account, I can tell that the hard drive is filled to the brim. I theorise that because sfill filled it up with junk data that never got erased like it should have, there isn't enough memory to deencrypt the user folder, any more.

What I want to know, is there any workaround to this? I still have Windows working in another partition, so if I shrink that somewhat and enlarge the one reserved for Ubuntu, would that help, or would it just break the encrypted folders completely? I ask because I've never had to deal with changing the sizes of encrypted (or partially encrypted) partitions before.

Answer (score 0):

`sfill` creates a file "oooooooo.ooo" or similar in the directory it receives as a parameter, so you can delete it from the guest account if you navigate to the directory `sfill` was told to operate in and remove the file, possibly as an elevated user.

These are the relevant lines from `sfill.c`:

```
char newname[strlen(argv[loop]) + 16];
strcpy(newname, argv[loop]); // can not overflow
...
    srand(getpid()+getuid());
...
    strcat(newname, "oooooooo.ooo");
...
            newname[counter] = 97+(int) (27.0 * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while booting, select "Advanced Options for Ubuntu", click on "Start Networking" and, when it returns, click on "Single User Mode".

Once in "Single User Mode" (and, running as `root`)

```
mount -a
```

Then find, and `rm` the big `sfill` file.

Comment: It appears that things aren't so easy, after all. I did not manage to find and delete the oooooooo.ooo file, as my home folders are encrypted but I did manage to delete an over 500Mb program via the root user, which I think ought to be enough free space to commence a  normal restart. No such luck; the system is still not letting me log in, nothing has changed.

Comment: OK, you sent me to the right direction, after all. Although it wasn't possible to remove the sfill-file through this method, I could remove a less important user and its home folder, and get things working, again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved. I was not able to touch the user folders, themselves, through the root, but I was able to delete users. Since I had two main users, one which wasn't as important as the other, I could delete the less important one and its home folder, releasing enough disk space from the right partition to log back in.

A very crude method, but functional.